# Select Distinct with multiple Inner Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to pull a list of patients and need to exclude all duplicate SubscriberNumber values. I can use the Select Distinct clause without the Where  (Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber = and it works fine. When I add the  (Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber = to my query it ignores my date range and pulls all appointments associated with the  SubscriberNumber

```
SELECT   Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber,  Encounter.DTTM, Patient_Iorg.OrganizationMrn AS MRN, Patient_Contact.HomePhoneArea, Patient_Contact.HomePhoneExchange, Patient_Contact.HomePhoneLast4, 
         Patient_Contact.LastName, Patient_Contact.FirstName, Patient_Contact.AddressLine1, Patient_Contact.AddressLine2, Patient_Contact.City, Patient_Contact.State, Patient_Contact.Zip, 
         Appointment.AppointmentStatusDE
FROM            Appointment INNER JOIN
                     Encounter ON Appointment.PatientID =   Encounter.PatientID INNER JOIN
                     Patient_Iorg INNER JOIN
                     Patient_Contact ON Patient_Iorg.PersonID = Patient_Contact.PatientID INNER JOIN
                     Primary_Insurance ON Patient_Iorg.PersonID = Primary_Insurance.patientid ON Encounter.PatientID = Primary_Insurance.patientid
WHERE           (Encounter.DTTM > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-06-15 00:00:00', 102)) AND (Encounter.DTTM >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-12-31 00:00:00', 102)) AND (Appointment.AppointmentStatusDE = 4) AND 
                     (Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber = '19803782') OR
                     (Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber = '19835428') OR
                     (Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber = '19914818') OR
                     (Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber = '19993082') OR
                     (Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber = '19993082') OR
                     (Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber = '19993082')
group BY             Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber, Encounter.DTTM, Patient_Iorg.OrganizationMrn, Patient_Contact.HomePhoneArea, Patient_Contact.HomePhoneExchange, Patient_Contact.HomePhoneLast4, 
                     Patient_Contact.LastName, Patient_Contact.FirstName, Patient_Contact.AddressLine1, Patient_Contact.AddressLine2, Patient_Contact.City, Patient_Contact.State, Patient_Contact.Zip, 
                     Appointment.AppointmentStatusDE;
```

Need to figure out how to use Distinct with multiple Where clauses and Inner Joins

Comment: What's the database/version?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the logic you intend is:

```
WHERE Encounter.DTTM > '2018-06-15' AND 
      Encounter.DTTM >= '2018-12-31' AND
      Appointment.AppointmentStatusDE = 4 AND 
      Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber IN ('19803782', '19835428', '19914818', '19993082', '19993082', '19993082')
```

Your query has a problem because there are no parentheses around the `OR` conditions.  However, instead of using parentheses, `IN` is much simpler and clearer.

Notice that I changed the date constants.  SQL Server is pretty good about converting values to dates.  I find this more readable.

Comment: You only need the one Encounter.DTTM > clause, `Encounter.DTTM > '2018-06-15' AND` is redundant in this case..

Comment: @PhilBaines . . . That is a really good point.  I left that logic in because it is the OP's logic.

Comment: Also, since most of your WHERE filters are outside your leading (innermost) table, I would try to move as much as possible to your joins. You can apply filters to the joins in the same way you apply them to a WHERE clause. This will provide a huge performance increase, especially if the tables are fairly large. You'll be able to see the difference in the execution plan.

Comment: Here is my new Where statement:     WHERE                    (Encounter.DTTM > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-06-15', 102)) AND (Encounter.DTTM >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2018-12-31', 102)) AND 
                         (Appointment.AppointmentStatusDE = 4) AND 
                         (Primary_Insurance.SubscriberNumber IN ('19803782', '19835428', '19914818', '19993082', '19993082', '19993082', '19993082'))

Comment: Only now it does not return any data.

Comment: @Dotnettex . . . It makes absolutely no difference if the conditions are in the `on` clause or the `where` clause.

Comment: @Gordon - Does this apply to all (any) joins, or just INNER joins?

Comment: @Dotnettex . . . The semantics change for `OUTER JOIN`s, so I guess it only applies generally to `INNER JOIN`s.